# What's the time complexity of std::lower_bound with std::set?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, set, complexity-theory

I know that there is `std::set::lower_bound` and the time complexity is `O(log)`, and i see that `std::lower_bound` is much slower than `std::set::lower_bound` when operates on `std::set`.

I googled and found this:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance

so it's clear that because of the `std::advance` is linear for `set::iterator`, the whole `std::lower_bound` takes up to `O(n)`.

However, it runs much faster than `O(n)` when i use it(and so did some friends say), can anybody explain why or tell me it's just not like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guaranteed complexity for `std::lower_bound()` is `O(n)` on non-random-access iterators. If this algorithm detects that the search is on an ordered associative container, it may take advantage of the tree structure possibly achieving a better conplexity. Whether any implementation does so, I don't know.

Comment: According to 25.4.3.1 lower_bound: Complexity: At most log2 (last − f irst) + O(1) comparisons.

Comment: @DieterLücking: complexity is always such a hard thing to define... Dietmar Kühl is here presenting the overall complexity whereas you are specifically targeting the number of comparisons. You thus both are right: in the worst case, it is O(N) in the number of iterations and O(log2(N)) in terms of the number of comparisons. Which ends up dominating the *run time* depends on the situation.

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl  "If this algorithm detects that the search is on an ordered associative container, it may take advantage"  are you sure in this?

Because https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound
tells us to use std::set::lower_bound  for std::set and std::multiset::lower_bound for std::multiset,   it calles "preferred" way  :) so does the std::lower_bound try to guess the datatype?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** whenever a container provides a method of the same name that an existing algorithm, it does so because the internal implementation is faster (relying on the container's properties) and thus you should just use it.

---

The problem is that complexity is fickle: O(N) **what** ?

The complexity guarantees on non-random-access iterators are:

- O(N) iterations
- O(log2(N)) comparisons

Depending whether iteration or comparison is the bottleneck, this actually changes everything!

In theory, in the case of sorted associative containers, one could wish to specialize `std::lower_bound` to take advantage of the fact that data is already sorted; however in practice it is relatively difficult. The major issue is that there is no telling that the comparison predicate of the `set` and that passed to `lower_bound` are indeed one and the same, and thus the algorithm need assume it is not the case (unless proven otherwise). And because the algorithm takes *iterators* instead of *ranges/container*, proving otherwise is *left as an exercise for the reader*.